# how to save to list and write variable name

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I need to implement the predicate

> term_variables

I need to get a term and return a list of variables (every variable only once).

for every new variable i check if its a member of a list if not then add the variable name to the list.

my problem is that when i save the variable in the list it gets saved a _g474 and i need to save it as the variable name X.

Is there any way to get the variables name?

Thanks

---

My Code:

```
term_variables(Term) :-
   Term=..L,
   term_variables(L, []).

term_variables([X| Xs], Vars):-
      compound(X),
      X=..L,
      term_variables(L, Vars)
   ;   
      var(X),
      not(member(X, Vars)),
      write(X),
      term_variables(Xs, [X|Vars])
   ;   
      term_variables(Xs, Vars).
term_variables([], _,).
```

Comment: Since many years, `term_variables/2` is a built-in predicate in SWI. So you cannot redefine it. Either you are using a very old version, or ...

Comment: I'm not trying to redefine it, i just need to implemented it... it needs to have a different name.